# Do users require a unique email with custom FBA?

Tags: 2013, email, forms-authentication

I'm looking into Sharepoint as a replacement for our extranet. I will be building a custom membership provider to hook into our existing membership database. However, our current setup does not require a user to have a unique email address.

I know it is fine/allowed for developing the custom implementation of `MembershipProvider` for a regular ASP.NTE site. Will a non-unique email be an issue for Sharepoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a unique email is not required using the SqlMembershipProvider.  It uses a username to login, instead of the user's email address.  There are no issues using it this way with SharePoint (and in fact that is how I have it configured in my development environment).